# UILabel alignment right issue

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem with UILabel in Swift. Problem happens when text is changed often (like a time readout) in the label.

With alignment left everything works perfect. But I need alignment right.

And in this mode text jumps left and right when changed. This jump is about 1 pixel.

May be someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Share some screenshots of the problem that you are facing. Verbally it's impossible to visualise things.

Comment: Post the code for how you create and update the label.

Comment: let elapsedTimeInSecondsLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = label.font.withSize(12)
        label.textAlignment = .right
        return label
    }()
Text:
20:20
20:21
20:22.

During change time in textAlignment = .right, 
text become 1 pixel left or right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the code in your comment:

```
label.font = label.font.withSize(12)
```

You are using the standard iOS system font, which is not monospaced, and therefore will cause spacing issues when the text changes. If you use a monospaced font (Courier, Menlo, etc), this issue will go away.

Alternatively, you could handle the drawing of the text yourself or adjust the font's kerning.